# Как сделать чтобы при скролле был переход по секциям?

Tags: javascript

```css
ul{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  li{
    margin-left: 30px;
    cursor:pointer
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Дом</li>
  <li>Работа</li>
  <li>Третье место</li>
</ul>
```

1. Как сделать чтобы при первом скролле был переход до Дома
2. При втором скролле был переход до Работа
3. При третьем скролле был переход до Третье место

Comment: А как будем измерять скролл?) Это событие запускается при любом сдвиге скроллбара, хоть на 1 пиксель. А для таких переходов явно указывают пройденное расстояние, например в пикселях... А можно разбить по времени... чтобы запускались при любом скролле, но не раньше, чем N секунд.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Здравствуйте можно код увидеть пожалуйста

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME  скиньте пожалуйста ссылку где про это можно почитать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например так (jQuery не имеет отношения к коду. Добавлено для наглядного демо):

```js
let u = 0; // Индекс для нужного переключения
let i = 0; // Для подсчета пройденного расстояния скролла
let x = 0; // Потому что захотелось

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  if( u > 2){return;} /* Элементов всего три штуки. Если индекс оказалсы выше 2,
  Разворачиваемся и больше ничего не выполняем */  
  i++; /* +1 для каждого проскролленного пикселя */
  
  if( i > x ){ // x == 0, первый переход произойдет сразу
    document.getElementsByTagName('li')[u].click();//кликаем на первый элемент
    u++;//увеличиваем u на единицу, на следующем круге кликнет на второй.
    
    x = 50*u; // Меняем значение x. Будет 50*1, потом 50*100. 
    /*Т.е. в следующий раз функция запустится только когда будет проскроллено еще 50 пикселей*/
  }
});


/*****************/

$('li').on('click', function(){
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  height: 1000px;
}

ul{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li{
  margin-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  width: 100px;
}
.active {
  color: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Дом</li>
  <li>Работа</li>
  <li>Третье место</li>
</ul>
```

А можно через `setTimeout`, менять значения переменных через 5 секунд, например. Тогда клик на новый элемент не произойдет, пока не пройдет 5 секунд.

Comment: я имел виду вот это https://get-element.3dn.ru/load/skroll_stranicy_po_sekcijam_s_ispolzovaniem_kolesa_myshi/1-1-0-549

Comment: пожалуйста скачайте и посмотрите